# Scoping "this" in angular and Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular7

In my angular-7 class, I am using jquery, I want to store all text from h4 tags in an array. But when I use *this* it only refers to angular's this and not jquery's *this*. I tried using the fat arrow as well but it didn't work for me.

I tried using callback parameters to access elements, but they stay undefined.

Here's my code. any suggestions/help is appreciated.

thanks.

```
$('h4').each((idx, elem) => {
            this.listItems.push({ id: idx, text: elem.innerText });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```
var that = this;
    $('h4').each(function (idx, elem) {
                //use that for angular component's this
                that.listItems.push({ id: idx, text: elem.innerText });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

arrow function do not create its own scope (this)
use normal function if you want to create function scope like this

```
var that=this;
    $('h4').each(function (idx, elem) {
                //use that for angular component's this
                this.listItems.push({ id: idx, text: elem.innerText });
            });
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but in this case I get empty *elem* and *idx*.

Comment: could you please show more code from the component.html and component.ts file